# What to do if an answer (possibly your own) solves the problem but you are also interested in why it occurs

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Earlier today I posted [a question on CSS animations that weren't working cross-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418009/animation-on-element-doesnt-run-in-chrome-opera-and-ie/). After a lot debugging I finally figured out that the problem lies in a single CSS property, `will-change`, that in some browsers causes animations on the same element not to take place.

Even though I **know** that this causes the problem (when I remove `will-change` everything is working smoothly), I would also like to know what the reason is. Is it simply a (known) browser bug, or is there a programmatical or logical reasoning behind this behaviour. Maybe I'm implementing the properties wrongly?

All questions I'd like to see answered, but no one will look at the question any longer, because I *have* the answer (animation doesn't work because will-change is in the same property list), but I also want to know *why*.

What is the best way to deal with this issue? I see a couple of options:

- **Add a bounty to draw attention.** Considering it's my own question and bounty, and I answered it myself, I am free to assign the bounty to whomever I feel explains the behaviour best. *However*, this would require other users to post answers that aren't answers to the original question (why isn't this working), but an answer to the underlying reason. Semantically, that doesn't seem correct.
- **Add a new question, while referring to the old one.** This seems redundant. Users will have to take a look at the original question any way.
- **Ask for comments.** Comments seem like a better place for an exposition of the underlying issue, but firstly comments aren't allowed to be quite long and secondly: there's no way to motivate and attract users to help out on an already answered and accepted answer.

Comment: Ask a new question seems the way to go

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ask a new question, that demonstrates the change, explains *what* happens when the change it makes, and asks why making that change causes the observed behavior.

> This seems redundant. Users will have to take a look at the original question any way.

Make sure to include enough information in the question such that this isn't the case.  Don't include any information that's no longer relevant, now that you know what you need to change, but *do* include enough information for anyone reading *just this question* to see the two different code snippets, be able to observe the changed behavior, and have an explanation of what you're seeing and why you're confused.

You can include a link to the original question if you want, but readers shouldn't *need* to follow it to be able to answer the question.

Comment: I'd love to see if anyone tries to dupe the new question against the old one on grounds that they both describe the same snippets of code.